# PHP Undefined array key login

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a PHP shop but if i try to login I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "userId" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/routes.php on line 79

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: moveCartProductsToAnotherUser(): Argument #1 ($sourceUserId) must be of type int, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/routes.php on line 79 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/functions/cart.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/routes.php(79): moveCartProductsToAnotherUser(NULL, 1) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/includes.php(8): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/index.php(7): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shop/functions/cart.php on line 69
```

cart.php:

```
function moveCartProductsToAnotherUser(int $sourceUserId,int $targetUserId):int{
    
    $oldCartItems = getCartItemsForUserId($sourceUserId);
    if(count($oldCartItems) === 0){
        return 0;
    }
    $movedProducts = 0;
        foreach($oldCartItems as $oldCartItem){
            addProductToCart($targetUserId,(int)$oldCartItem['product_id'],(int)$oldCartItem['quantity']);
            $movedProducts += deleteProductInCartForUserId($sourceUserId,(int)$oldCartItem['product_id']);
        }
        return $movedProducts;
    }
```

routes.php:

```
        if(0 === count($errors)){
            $_SESSION['userId'] = (int)$userData['id'];
            moveCartProductsToAnotherUser($_COOKIE['userId'],(int)$userData['id']);

            setcookie('userId',(int)$userData['id'],strtotime('+30 days'),$baseURL);
            $redirectTarget = $baseURL.'index.php';
            
            if(isset($_SESSION['redirectTarget'])){
                $redirectTarget = $_SESSION['redirectTarget'];
            }
            header("Location: ". $redirectTarget);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

But when I go to the start page, I'm logged in.
would be nice if someone could help. thank you:)

modify code. nothing

Comment: You are passing userid in a cookie to **moveCartProductsToAnotherUser** BEFORE you are creating that cookie. Also with your code, your source and target users are the same.